# Keras model only generates a plane when trying to approximate a math function

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to approximate a function f(x,y) using a single hidden layer perceptron (required that is single layer) by generating a meshgrid of 10,000 points between [-1,1] for both x and y, calculating f(x,y) and adding some gaussian distributed random noise to each f(x,y) to generate my training, validation, and testing sets.

When I train my model, I get a MSE of about .04.

The **problem** is when I then use my model to predict new data and graph it, I get a plane-like structure which looks absolutely nothing like the function.

I've tried to debug this for many hours and here is what I've found:

Predicting all f(x,y) using the mesh grid (basically making predictions for training, validation, and test sets) yields the plane structure

Training for less epochs - training for more epochs only seemed to change the slope of the plane and not the shape.

Here is my code:

```
num_points = 100
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, num_points)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, num_points)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

def f(x,y):
    q = (np.sin(20 * ((x**2 + y**2) ** (1/2))))/(20 * ((x**2 + y**2) ** (1/2)))
    w = 1/5 * np.cos(10 * ((x**2 + y**2) ** (1/2)))
    e = y/2
    r = -.3
    return q + w + e + r
fxy = np.zeros((num_points, num_points))
for row in range(len(xx)):
    for col in range(len(xx[0])):
        fxy[row][col] = f(xx[row][col], yy[row][col])
noise = .1*np.random.normal(0, 1, fxy.shape)
fxyhat = fxy + noise

def split(xx, yy, fxy):
    num_samples = xx.size
    print(num_samples)
    num_train = int(num_samples*.7)
    num_val = int(num_samples*.15)

    all_data = []
    for row in range(len(xx)):
        for col in range(len(xx[0])):
            all_data.append((xx[row][col], yy[row][col], fxy[row][col]))

    random.shuffle(all_data)
    print(len(all_data))
    train = np.array(all_data[0:num_train])
    val = np.array(all_data[num_train:num_train + num_val])
    test = np.array(all_data[num_train+num_val:len(all_data)])

    return train, val, test

train, val, test = split(xx, yy, fxyhat)

train_x = np.array([[data[0],data[1]] for data in train])
train_y = np.array([data[2] for data in train])

val_x = np.array([[data[0],data[1]] for data in test])
val_y = np.array([data[2] for data in test])

test_x = np.array([[data[0],data[1]] for data in test])
test_y = np.array([data[2] for data in test])

all_x = np.concatenate((train_x, val_x, test_x),axis=0)
all_y = np.concatenate((train_y, val_y, test_y),axis=0)

model = Sequential()
# first layer
model.add(Dense(num_nodes, input_dim=2, activation='sigmoid',)) 
# output layer
model.add(Dense(1))

optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=init_learning_rate, momentum=momentum) 
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer)

num_nodes = 26
epochs = 1
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=len(train_x))
```

My function with noise looks like this (training data):
[image: My function with noise looks like this (training data)]

and my predictions look like this:
[image: and my predictions look like this]

Has anyone run into errors where their models just generate planes when trying to generate predictions for a dense grid?

Comment: Can you post more of your code or link to a colab notebook? The only way I can reproduce this is by not adding an activation function.

Comment: Posted more code. Thank you!

Comment: You still haven't supplied the learning rate or momentum you're using!

Comment: Sorry! I'm in a country right now where it's hard for me to get internet access. lr = .1, momentum=.9, epochs=10000

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite a plane. The plot you're using is deceptive. A scatter plot shows a more clear picture.

[image]

Notice the edges are curving up a little.

At 2000 epochs, the curvature at the edges is far more pronounced, and the network has started to recognize the center.

[image]

After 100K epochs, here's the picture you'd see:

[image]

Here's the code for training and plotting.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def plot_preds(XY_test, z_pred):
  x = XY_test[:,0]
  y = XY_test[:,1]
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
  ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
  # Since we're centered at (0,0), these colors should emphasize the droplet
  d = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
  scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, z_pred, c=d, cmap='coolwarm')
  ax.set_xlabel('x')
  ax.set_ylabel('y')
  ax.set_zlabel('z')


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(26, input_dim=2, activation='relu',)) 
model.add(Dense(1))
optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer)

history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=100000, batch_size=len(train_x), verbose=0)
z_pred = model.predict(test_x)
plot_preds(test_x, z_pred)
```

Comment: How did you modify my code? Did you just change the number of epochs when training the model? Also, could you please show the code for making that scatterplot? Thank you so much! This was such a great help

Comment: I only changed the epochs of training. Scatterplot code has been added.